# How to display a blade page using ajax in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I have a problem with my ajax and blade in Laravel 4.2. I am not able to display this(given below) particular blade using ajax.
I have used this same method to display another pages and was successful too.

This is my view which sends ajax request

```
<td>{{HTML::linkRoute('campaign.preview','Run>>',$list1->id,['class'=>'button tiny radius','data-reveal-id'=>'comment-show','data-reveal-ajax'=>'true']) }}
```

Route

```
    Route::model('list1', 'List1');

    Route::model('campaign', 'Campaign');

    Route::model('template','Template');

    Route::get('/campaigns/{list1}/preview',[
    'as' => 'campaign.preview', 
    'uses' => 'CampaignController@previewCampaign'
    ]);
```

Controller

```
public function previewCampaign(List1 $list1s)
{
    $tid = Session::get('template');
    $templates = Template::find($tid);
    if (Request::ajax()){

        return View::make('campaigns.preview')
        ->with(compact('list1s'))
        ->with(compact('templates'));
    }
}
```

The blade which has to be viewed

```
 <p> <font size="5" face="verdana" color="green">{{{$templates->title}}}</font></p>
 <p> <b><font size="5" face="Comic Sans MS" color="#8904B1">{{{$templates->description}}}</font></b></p>
 <p><figure>
       <img width="720" height="900" src='{{ asset($templates->detailImageURL) }}'> 
 </figure></p>

 <p><b>Expires on:&nbsp;</b><font  face="verdana" color="red"> {{{$templates->end_date}}}</FONT></p>

 <p><b>Click here to claim the offer:</b><a href='{{$templates->targetURL}}'>&nbsp;{{$templates->targetURL}}</a></p>
 <p><b><font size="2" face="verdana" color="blue">Do you want to run this campaign on {{{$list1s->name}}} ?</font></b></p>
 <span class="right">&nbsp; &nbsp;{{ HTML::link('user/campaigns/save','Yes',['class' => 'button tiny radius']) }}</span>&nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="right">{{ HTML::link('user/campaigns/new','No',['class' => 'button tiny radius']) }}     </span>
  </p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
```

When I try to run this code the page is no being displayed , but only fades the display.
Any suggestion  about my problem?